# iMPORTXML is returning #NA (imported content is empty) in some cells and #REF in some cells in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok. so i'm tring to import a couple of data from different urls on the same google sheet using IMPORTXML function. it works on some cells and it returns #NA (imported content is empty) on some and #REF(Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in H16.) on some cells. I need help right now.
This is the formula in one of the cells returning #NA  imported content is empty:

=IMPORTXML(N9;"//ul[@class='important-attributes-list']/li[2]/div/div")

And this is the url i am extracting the data from:

https://www.tim.pl/koncowka-oczkowa-miedziana-km-3510-e11km-01010104100

This is the formula in one of the cells returning #REF Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in H16.:

=IMPORTXML(N15;"//ul[@class='important-attributes-list']/li[1]/div/a/div/span/span/span")

And this is the url it is extracting data from:

https://www.tim.pl/aparatura-elektryczna/elementy-sterowania-i-sygnalizacji/przyciski-sterownicze-kompletne/?filters%5Bmanufacturer.keyword%5D=schneider+electric&filters%5Bseria_u_dostawcy.keyword%5D=harmony&filters%5BEF000190__kolor_przycisku.keyword%5D=Czerwony&filters%5BEF001142__z_podswietleniem.keyword%5D=Tak

If you want to check ouut the spreadsheet itself, this is the link to it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q7IV_i--1artQMzqx3O-7YGqe-_HDljCRm8bFX4tsRc/edit?usp=sharing

I do appreciate every help you can render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### #REF!

... means that the result is an array (not only one value) and there is not enough space to display the result

For instance, in G12, `=IMPORTXML(N12;"//h1")` the formula gives back 4 values in G12:J12, you need free places on the right hand side of G12

To get the first one, you can do `=index(IMPORTXML(N12;"//h1");1;1)` or join the values `=textjoin(" ";;IMPORTXML(N12;"//h1"))`

[image]

### #N/A

... in E12 and F12 is due to the lack of ul class=`breadcrumbs__list theme--light` in the source of the web page, clarify whar you are looking for

in F12 you can use

```
=index(IMPORTXML(N12;"//a[@class='product-link-attribute__link']");2;1)
```

You should probably reduce the number of calls inside the urls

### edit:

**reduce drastically the numbers of calls**, for instance, in I9, you could fetch all data at once using this **global xpath**

```
"//ul[@class='important-attributes-list']"
```

it will be easy then to detailed the informations inside the multi-cells result

**This will solve quite 100% of your errors.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate this. Do you have any solution to the #NA?

Comment: added in the answer, please clarify what you are looking for

Comment: I don't understand that. can you please give me exact instructions to following in resolving the #NA error? I'm kinda new to this

Comment: see the answer for F12 ... you have to look inside the source to get the right parameters, it's a big job

Comment: it worked for F12!!! Thanks a lot. i really do appreciate this. Can you give me precise steps on how I can perform this for others cells with #NA?

Comment: in E12, it seems there is no `Grupa`  in the web page

Comment: For others, I take a look at the source of the web page (right click on page > source) and I am looking for the terme I wish to fetch, then I am looking for a specific tag for that text before it

Comment: Please I need to ask you a favor. Can you help me out by resolving all the errors on the sheet. I know it's a big request. But I've been on this for way too long now. It's almost becoming a problem.

Comment: After 2 hours of effort, your spreadsheet still continue to attempt the results. I suggest in edit answer to change and use global xpath for multi-infos at once.

Comment: 2 hours! I can't thank you enough! How do I use the global xpath?

Comment: It worked! But some attributes are missing. Attributes like photo, Grupa, delivered spare parts and price are missing

Comment: take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SNxSefYZsT1rVogm5blbWEk_z6jIapiy0Nm5cBV6Wa4/copy I put 2 formulas (yellow, blue) that you can drag. This will be much quicker. Sometimes, however, the information is absent from the web page.